# labview application on XP

Tags: dll, windows-xp, labview

I try to open a labview application for a bench test acquisition coupled to e.bloxx network (GANTNER INSTRUMENTS), it shows me this error

> It's the application's model. it can't be used alone

This app worked fine until yesterday. My operating system is windows XP professional.
Any help!

Answer (score 0):

That is not likely to be a LabVIEW error -- the NI errors do not typically use "It's" contractions, especially not without some indication of what "it" is in context. I certainly have not seen that text, nor did I find it in any of the know string files of LabVIEW. I think this is an error specific to your application, so you are unlikely to get any help from Stack Overflow. I recommend that you check with your app vendor/author.

Comment: Thanks for your response! what do you think about a probem with windows XP. i tried the delete the app. i reinstall it! it works fine but within 20 minutes when i try to open it it shows the same error

Comment: That definitely sounds like an app specific problem. Maybe it is running out of memory? Check how much memory your app is using over time with Task Manager.

Comment: this app is installed on another spare labtop. It shows thé same error

Comment: How van i fix this memory problem if so

Comment: Rewrite your application. It isn’t a bug in LabVIEW or in the OS. It’s a bug in your software... it is acquiring resources and not freeing them. What exactly? No one can tell you except the person who wrote the application.